# Azure ARM template how to get correct syntax from utcnow function to runbook start time

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

It should look like this:

```
"startTime": "2019-03-29T23:30:00+01:00"
```

With default I get

```
20190430T151332Z
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the desired syntax. Is that possible with ARM template utcnow function and if yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd need to use standard dotnet custom formatting. As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

```
"[utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss zzzz')]"
```

this seems to be fine, except it returns not your TZ, but ARM TZ, so it always returns +00:00. so it makes no sense to use it.

Comment: yes I now get: Error message: The start time of the schedule must be 
at least 5 minutes after the time you create the schedule.

Comment: well, thats not something I can help you with,it doesnt allow for custom time. besides the fact that its a completely different problem. your question is answered, i suggest you accept this answer and create a new question. But I dont think its solveable with arm templates

Comment: Yes I do accept your answer. I found one user request to make the time function more usable but it is yet implemented.

Comment: i dont know why the implemented it in such a ridiculous way. :(

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is correct to get the desired syntax but it doesn't solve issue with error: 'the start time of the schedule must be at least 5 minutes after the time you create the schedule' when used in a schedule. To solve it, simply add required hours using dateTimeAdd. For example if you want to start the schedule one hour from deployment use:

```
"scheduleTime": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "[dateTimeAdd(utcNow('u'), 'PT1H', 'yyyy-MM-dd THH:mm:ss zzzz')]"
}
```